Do divinities agree to share food offers?
On a particular occasion it happened to offer many foods to Ganesha and a single biscuit each for two other deities.
However the other two deities appreciated.
But, I wonder if it is possible to offer the same foods to two or three deities in the same Puja, in short: do the divinities agree to share the same offers?
Reflecting on this question, I can think of considering the diversity of the divinities, for example Ganesha and Kali, perhaps Kali (I am not informed) also accepted impure offers, but perhaps also the same as Ganesha.
Thanks!

Not among themselves. You may split a biscuit, if need be. As per my experiences.

What you said in the post is not exactly sharing food .. in separate plates foods are offered to separate deities in the same Puja and that is quite commonplace and normal .. However, food offered to one deity is not accepted by another deity .. also remnants (impure food in your words) are accepted by only Ucchistha Ganapati and Ucchishta Matangi not by any other deities
